# Android Power Button Double Press

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-toast

What i am trying to do is ,double clicking the power button will raise a toast "Sending Message", doesn't matter if screen is On or Off.Somehow managed to write this code
What i have done is , i have recorded the time duration of the clicks on power button & If the difference b/w them is less than a 1sec, then it will raise the toast.
But its raising the toast only when screen is off or locked not when screen is on..What to do. Please help

1. `MainActivity.java`

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
       filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
       BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver();
       registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
       }

   @Override
       protected void onPause() {
           // when the screen is about to turn off
           if (CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
               // this is the case when onPause() is called by the system due to a screen state change
               System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED OFF");

       } else {
           // this is when onPause() is called when the screen state has not changed
       }
       super.onPause();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       // only when screen turns on
       if (!CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver.wasScreenOn) {
           // this is when onResume() is called due to a screen state change
           System.out.println("SCREEN TURNED ON");
       } else {
           // this is when onResume() is called when the screen state has not changed
       }
       super.onResume();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
           // Do something here...
           Log.d("ONKEYDOWN", "ONKEYDOWN");
           event.startTracking(); // Needed to track long presses
           return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
           // Do something here...
           Log.d("onKeyLongPress", "ONKEYDOWN");
           return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
   }
   @Override
   public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
       if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
           Log.d("dispatchKeyEvent", "ONKEYDOWN");

           return true;
       }

       return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
   }
   }
   ```
2. `CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver.java`

public class CloseSystemDialogsIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;
static long prevTime=0;
static long currTime=0;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        // do whatever you need to do here
        prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN ON","CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN ON");
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        // and do whatever you need to do here
        Log.d("CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN ON","CHECK IN RECIVER WHEN OFF");
        currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
    if (currTime>0 && prevTime>0) {
        if ((currTime - prevTime) < 1000 && (currTime - prevTime)>-1000) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "double Clicked power button",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("eciver ", "double Clicked power button");
            currTime = 0;
            prevTime = 0;
        }
    }
   }
   }
```

1. `Android Manifest File`

   `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raising a toast when Power Button is pressed twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277324/raising-a-toast-when-power-button-is-pressed-twice)

Comment: @bhanukaushik have you done with this? i am in a same boat

Comment: tried a lot but ends up with the code above...